# (Swift) didSelectItemAtIndexPath in UICollectionView defined in external view doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is my problem. I have made a View Controller which inherited from UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate. So, I have this:

```
class myController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
...
}
```

And then, I made a custom view that it has a UICollectionView, something like this:

```
class externalCollectionView: UIView {
    var myCollection: UICollectionView?

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 130, height: 130)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10

        myCollection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 120, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - 120), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollection!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "customCellView", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myItem")

        self.addSubview(myCollection!)
    }
}
```

So, into my view controller I set delegate methods and features with this code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
    customView = externalCollectionView(frame: self.view.frame)
    customView.myCollection!.dataSource = self
    customView.myCollection!.delegate = self
    customView.myCollection!.userInteractionEnabled = true
    customView.myCollection!.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

with this, the method didSelectItemAtIndexPath never is called. Yes, I have a custom cell collection view (in a xib), but I even have made it without graphical elements (empty) and the method is not called. I have implemented several solutions that I have found  on Internet but nothing works. Anyone have idea what is happen?

Comment: Are you missing a super.init() call?

Comment: Sorry @pbasdf, I call super.init(). I have already edited.

Comment: Are other touch events being passed to the collection view - does it scroll OK?

Comment: @pbasdf no, the scroll not works. But I don't have another view that can block the interaction

Comment: How is the view controller itself presented?

Comment: @pbasdf in my self.view I added a view with content, then when the user tap in a button and UICollectionView view appears in front of all views.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to connect from Storyboard or Xib your UICollectionViewCell to file's owner delegate and dataSource? maybe this could help

Comment: the others method for example numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath execute well. The only case is didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally overriding - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath? check "select" against "deselect" method

Comment: in fact, I am trying to implement both of them, and they not executing. I'm completely sure that I haven't override this methods.

Comment: ok so in your base view controller implement that method and do nothing inside, than reimplement in your subclass and it should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` for the custom view. If the parent view has no user interaction enabled, then it's subviews won't recognise any touch events.